# does any one know server support php and oracle 10g

Tags: php, oracle10g

i am searching in the internet for server i can upload my project on it my project developed by php and oracle so need server support both php as programming language and oracle as db

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the price of an oracle license it's *very* unlikely that you will find a hosting company offering this on shared servers.

You could get a server with root access or a managed server though and then buy an oracle license and install it on there (or have whoever is managing your server install it).

**However, it might be much easier and cheaper for you if you switched to MySQL!**

Comment: actually im pro php + mysql but client want me do it by php + oracle so what i can do............any way i need server support oracle

Answer (score 0):

You can usually configure a VPS or Dedicated Server with any software you require.

Answer (score 0):

AWS can provide Oracle database services - but you need to buy your DBA from them as well. There's no end of hosting companies offering bare vhosts where you can install Oracle and PHP.